# Paypal REST Api update recurring amount

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

Paypal seems to be pushing for using the REST API, but I have not found a way to implement a basic recurring payment functionality such as the one below.

I have the following scenario: user subscribes to three products using their credit card, then two months later the user decides to remove one of the products. How do I go about updating the recurring amount? The only way I have been able to do this so far is by creating a new plan and new agreement, and I find it quite odd to ask the user to reenter their credit card and address information when they are removing a product from their subscription - I could maybe see it if they were adding one or perhaps just asking for the CVV.

Things I have tried:

1. Updating the amount of a plan - an exception is thrown telling me that property cannot be patch updated.
2. Creating a new plan, and assigning the agreement to this new plan - same error as above.
3. Storing the credit card in the vault, then using it to create a new agreement - well you cannot use a stored credit card to create an agreement.

Updating the amount is very easily done using the classic API, and unless I am missing something here it would appear that paypal is pushing for a product that lacks basic functionality.

Secondly, return_url and cancel_url seem to be required, this is an agreement based on a credit card.

Thanks